# Android getting element from ArrayList<LatLng>()

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an array list, ArrayList(), which is used to save lat and lng. I want to get the element inside this array, in order to calculate the distance.

```
private void whereAmI(){

    Location location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    updateWithNewLocation(location);

    //GPS Listener
    manager.addGpsStatusListener(gpsListener);

    //Location Listener
    int minTime = 0;//ms
    int minDist = 0;//meter
    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, minTime, minDist, locationListener);
}

GpsStatus.Listener gpsListener = new GpsStatus.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        switch (event) {
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STARTED:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_STARTED");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS_EVENT_STARTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_STOPPED:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS_EVENT_STOPPED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                Log.d("x=", "GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS");
                break;
        }
    }
};

LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        updateWithNewLocation(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
                Log.v("x=", "Status Changed: Out of Service");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Status Changed: Out of Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.v("x=", "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Status Changed: Temporarily Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
                Log.v("x=", "Status Changed: Available");
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Status Changed: Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

};

private void showMarkerMe(double lat, double lng){
    if (markerMe != null) {
        markerMe.remove();
    }

    MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOpt.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
    markerOpt.title("I am here!");
    markerMe = mMap.addMarker(markerOpt);

    //Toast.makeText(this, "lat:" + lat + ",lng:" + lng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private void cameraFocusOnMe(double lat, double lng){
    CameraPosition camPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .zoom(16)
            .build();

    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(camPosition));
}

private void trackToMe(double lat, double lng){
    if (traceOfMe == null) {
        traceOfMe = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    }
    traceOfMe.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

    calculateDistance(traceOfMe);

    PolylineOptions polylineOpt = new PolylineOptions();
    for (LatLng latlng : traceOfMe) {
        polylineOpt.add(latlng);
    }

    polylineOpt.color(Color.RED);

    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOpt);
    line.setWidth(10);
}

private void calculateDistance(ArrayList<LatLng> points) {

    for (int i =0; i < points.size() -1; i++) {
        LatLng pointA =  points.get(i);
        LatLng pointB = points.get(i + 1);
        float[] results = new float[3];
        Location.distanceBetween (pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude, pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude, results);
        totalD +=  results[0];
    }
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

    String where = "";
    if (location != null) {

        double lng = location.getLongitude();

        double lat = location.getLatitude();

        float speed = location.getSpeed();

        long time = location.getTime();
        String timeString = getTimeString(time);

        speedList.add(""+ speed);

        where = "Lng: " + lng +
                "  Lat: " + lat +
                "  Speed: " + speed +
                "\nTime: " + timeString +
                "  Provider: " + "gps" +
                "  Distance: " + totalD ;


        showMarkerMe(lat, lng);
        cameraFocusOnMe(lat, lng);
        trackToMe(lat, lng);

    }else{
        where = "No location found.";
    }


    txt.setText(where);
}
```

I use the codes above to track the route, i want to calculate the total distance, using distanceBetween, but i don't know how to do it.

Comment: You want trip distance or distance between two points only ?

Comment: i wanna calculate the total distance traveled

Comment: GMapV2Direction md = new GMapV2Direction();Document doc = md.getDocument(latLngIst, latlng2nd, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
            ArrayList<LatLng> traceOfMe= md.getDirection(doc);



    PolylineOptions polylineOpt = new PolylineOptions();
    for (LatLng latlng : traceOfMe) {
        polylineOpt.add(latlng);
    }


    polylineOpt.color(Color.RED);

    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOpt);
    line.setWidth(10);

Comment: This method will save the lat and lng when there is location change, so i want to know how to use the elements inside the array list to calculate the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through all the point of your trajectory. 
And call distanceBetween for each segment of your path.

The distanceBetween method take a float[] paramters and store the results in it.

results[0] = the distance between the two points in meters.

results[1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) = the initial bearing (Seems it is not always set)

results[2] = the final bearing (Seems it is not always set)

For more information see the documentation [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]))

So Something like that should do the job

```
private float calculateDistance(ArrayList<LatLng> points) {
    float totalDistance = 0f;
    for (int i =0; i < points.size() -1; i++ {
        LatLng pointA =  points.get(i);
        LatLng pointB = points.get(i + 1);
        float[] results = new float[3];
        Location.distanceBetween (pointA.latitude, pointA.longitude, pointB.latitude, pointB.longitude, results);
        totalDistance +=  results[0];
    }
    return totalDistance;
}
```

Here is a more optimised solution :

In your activiy you store two variables

`LatLng previousLocation
    float totalDistance`

then in your onLocationChanged method. You call the addToDistance method like that

```
// Goes inside your Location listener
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    updateWithNewLocation(location);
    addToDistance(location);
}

// Goes inside your activity
public void addToDistance(LatLng newPoint) {
        if (previousLocation !=  null) { 
            float[] results = new float[3];
            Location.distanceBetween (previousLocation.latitude, previousLocation.longitude, newPoint.latitude, newPoint.longitude, results);
        totalDistance +=  results[0];
        } 
        previousLocation = newPoint;
}
```

Comment: So i create this method, and then inside the trackToMe method, i add calculateDistance(traceOfMe); ?

Comment: It depends how you want to use the distance ?

Comment: I want to calculate the distance traveled since the tracking is on and when there is location change, the traceOfMe array list stores the lat and lng of the route, i just want to use it to calculate the distance traveled.

Comment: then you can call this method from track to Me. but a more efficient approach would be to calculate the distance between the last point registered and the new point given by on location change. The same for drawing.

Comment: Can you show how you get the locations changes I will be able to come up with a more optimized answer

Comment: When there is new location change, the array list will store the new point inside it. So your method can calculate the distance at each two points? As the result of only calculating the starting and ending point in the whole journey is not what i want.

Comment: What do you want to calculate the distance between start point and endpoint or the the total distance of the trip ?

Comment: ok i have edited the code, and added the method you gave me above, you can take a look. i want to calculate the total distance traveled by adding all segments.

Comment: That is what the method I have given you is doing. As you can see it goest through all the point in your travel

Comment: See more optimized approach both of them should have the same result regarding the distance calculated

Comment: What are the units of this measure? km ? meters ? feets ?